# Pivot json data from array of models

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, asp.net-web-api, pivot

I host a web api service, which returns a snapshot of my model "myModel" for the last 12 months. The json array that I receive on my client is a simple array of 12 "myMydel" objects.

If myModel has properties "foo" and "bar", is there an efficient way in javascript to pivot the array to result in a collection of arrays of properties, for example:

*i'd like to transform*

```
history{
  myModel[]
     myModel[0]
       foo: 1
       bar: 2
       Key: 1
     myModel[1]
       foo: 3
       bar: 4
       Key: 1
 }
```

*into*

```
history{
    "1"{  //key
      foo[] 
        foo[0]: 1
        foo[1]: 3
      bar[]
         bar[0]: 2
         bar[1]: 4
      }
  }
```

I am open to implementing on the server side if that would be more efficient. My api service is a .NET 4.5 Web Api.

So again. My question is, is there a super efficient way to achieve these results in javascript? If not, is there one in c#? Can someone provide some simple example code to get me going?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT: Working code**

Even though I was voted down on this, i figure I'd provide a working example of javascript that achieves this. It's pretty fast too. Note that each history record must have a Key to group records by.

```
  _pivot = function(history) {
    var i, pivoted, prop, rec;
    pivoted = {};
    if (history !== null) {
      i = 0;
      while (i < history.length) {
        rec = history[i];
        pivoted[rec.Key] = pivoted[rec.Key] || {};
        for (prop in rec) {
          pivoted[rec.Key][prop] = pivoted[rec.Key][prop] || [];
          if (!pivoted[rec.Key][prop].date) {
            pivoted[rec.Key][prop].push({
              value: rec[prop]
            });
          }

        }
        i++;
      }
      return pivoted;
    }
    return null;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as super efficient, I think unless you change your underling model, you are going to have to just iterate through your model, either server side or client side and assign each property to a different array.

```
var tempFoo = newArray(); tempBar = newArray();
for (var i = 0; i < myModel.length; i++){
    tempFoo.push(myModel[i].foo);
    tempBar.push(myModel[i].bar);
}
```

Also, if you have it sorted in your server side code, or if it is just automatically sorted from whatever database you are pulling from, you will see speed increases. [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Hope this helps, fyi, the example is Javascript.

V/R